# Makefile: recursive macro call running indefinitely

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile which creates a custom filesystem and my problem is to copy some packages inside it. I need to process a directory containing all the packages that I need to include, but each package may or may not contain a file associated describing its dependencies. Here is an excerpt of what I've tried to do:

```
PKGS_DIR := $(shell pwd)/packages
PKGS := $(wildcard $(PKGS_DIR)/*.pkg)

.PHONY: $(PKGS)

define getdeps
    @if [ ! -f $(2)/$(1) ]; then \
        echo $(1) >> $(BASE_DIR)/deplist.tmp; \
        if [ -f $(PKGS_DIR)/$(1).dep ]; then \
            depapps=`cat $(PKGS_DIR)/$(1).dep`; \
            $(foreach depapp,$$depapps,\
                $(call getdeps,$(depapp),$(BASE_DIR)/optional); \
            ) \
        fi \
    fi
endef

$(PKGS):
    @echo processing $(notdir $@)
    $(call getdeps,$(notdir $@),$(BASE_DIR)/optional)
```

With this code, my makefile crashes because it enters in an indefinitely loop and I'm not understanding why.
My question is: Is it possible to make a recursive call in a macro definition? Is there a better way to implement this? Perhaps it would be better using a shell script to implement this and just call it inside my makefile.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make doesn't seem like the right tool for this. What is the nature of these dependencies, and what tool will use the list?

Comment: The dependencies are also packages, and the intention is to use the list inside the proper makefile. Let me try to explain a little better: inside the packages dirs there are: 1.pkg, 2.pkg and 1.pkg.dep. "1.pkg.dep" is just a file containing a list of packages that 1 depends on to be installed, which is in this case, 2.pkg.

Comment: You don't mean *build* dependencies, do you? If so, you're doing it all wrong.

Comment: No no, they are already built. They just need to be copied to the filesystem folder, but respecting the order of dependencies in order to be loaded correctly.

Comment: So if you tell Make to install `1.pkg`, it should also install `2.pkg`, is that right?

Comment: The direct answer to your headline question is that normally `make` spots recursive macro definitions, whether directly or indirectly recursive.  Thus: `X = a ${X} b` is spotted as directly recursive and `X = a ${Y} b` plus `Y = c ${X}` is spotted as indirectly recursive.  Immediate evaluation (the `:=` notation) alters things.  The `+=` notation avoids being directly recursive.  I'm not clear why your makefile is going off indefinitely.  Are you sure it is `make` and not something else?  How do you know it is `make` that is going haywire?

Comment: That's right @Beta, 1 depends on 2 and I need to install 2 previously in order to load 1 correctly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, talking about the crazy crash, I can't tell if its related to make or something else, because the shell gets locked and I need to hit ^C to stop make running. Is there a way to debug?

Comment: One debugging step is to remove the `@` markers so you can see what `make` is doing.  Another step is to review your recursive function; what is the stop criterion?  What creates `$(2)/$(1)` if it was not there beforehand?

Comment: In this case, $(1) is the name of the pkg that is going to be installed and $(2) is the auxiliary directory where the pkgs will be copied into, before getting extracted (installed) to the filesystem. I'll try removing the @ markers and reply with new results

Comment: And you're sure there are no circular dependencies?

Comment: Didn't get anything new, the shell gets stucked even after removing the @ markers. I also looked into the dependencies files and didn't find circular dependencies @Beta. I started simulating this code in a shell script and the recursion was ok. Somehow I got this strange behavior in my makefile